# How to parse HTML text and links with java and jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-parsing

I need to parse text from a webpage. The text is presented in this way:

```
nonClickableText= link1 link2  nonClickableText2= link1 link2
```

I want to be able to convert all to a string in java. The non clickable text should remain like it is while the clickable text should be replaced with its actual link.

So in java I would have this:

```
String parsedHTML = "nonClickableText= example.com example.com nonClickableText2= example3.com example4.com";
```

Here are some pictures: [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vj8U.png) [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGkys.png)

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Please post precise input and output needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is `link1` and `link2`? According to your example

> "... nonClickableText2= example3.com example4.com"

they can be different, so what would be the source besides the `href`?

Based on you images the following code should give you everything to adopt your final string presentation. First we grab the `<strong>`-block and then go through the child nodes, using `<a>`-children with preceding text-nodes:

```
String htmlString = "<html><div><p><strong>\"notClickable1\"<a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"example1.com\">clickable</a>\"notClickable2\"<a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"example2.com\">clickable</a>\"notClickable3\"<a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"example3.com\">clickable</a></strong></p></div></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString); //can be replaced with Jsoup.connect("yourUrl").get();
String parsedHTML = "";

Element container = doc.select("div>p>strong").first();

for (Node node : container.childNodes()) {
    if(node.nodeName().equals("a") && node.previousSibling().nodeName().equals("#text")){
        parsedHTML += node.previousSibling().toString().replaceAll("\"", "");
        parsedHTML += "= " + node.attr("href").toString() + " ";
    }
}
parsedHTML.trim();

System.out.println(parsedHTML);
```

Output:

```
notClickable1= example1.com notClickable2= example2.com notClickable3= example3.com
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, with a little tweaking I was able to get it working. But my answer is still partially unaswered: if I have the URL of the page how can I let the program grab the <strong> block by itself?

Comment: If the content is not generated with javascript, you can grab the site with: `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("yourUrl").get();`

Comment: If it is dynamically generated content you would have to use something like htmlunit. I also recommend the new documentation entries regarding jsoup: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsoup/topics.

Comment: You get `textIWant` with `node.childNode(0)`. (Please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer).

Comment: Thanks I also managed to do that with container.text() but with a slight different result. Anyway votes don't show up cause reputation but I already did that.